# Why does this code not populate my combobox with the array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, combobox

```
Sub Auto_Open()

NumElements = Range(.Range("D6"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Dim arr(), i As Long
Redim arr(1 to NumElements,1 to 2)
    With Worksheets(5)
    For i=1 to NumElements
        arr(i,1)=cells(4+i,4)     ' column D
        arr(i,2)=cells(4+i,5)     ' column E
    Next 
    Me.ComboBox1 = arr
    End With

End Sub
```

What im trying to do is to create a combobox that will be populated by an array made out of two columns that are in a different sheet.

Update:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
With Worksheets(5)
NumElements = Range(.Range("D6"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Dim arr(), i As Long
Redim arr(1 to NumElements,1 to 2)
    For i=1 to NumElements
        arr(i,1)=cells(4+i,4)     ' column D
        arr(i,2)=cells(4+i,5)     ' column E
    Next 
    Me.Combobox = arr
    End With
End Sub
```

update 2:

```
Sub Auto_Open()

With Worksheets(5)
    Dim erg As Range: Set erg = .Range(.Range("D6"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2)
    Dim arr As Variant: arr = erg.Value
    Worksheets(1).ComboBox1 = arr
    End With

End Sub
```

I got this now but it tells me there is a type mismatch on the combobox line.

Comment: Your code will not compile, `.Range` (with leading dot) needs a With-statement

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: With will stop you having to type Worksheets(5), so i'd imaging .range() belongs to worksheets(5) so .Range(.Range("D6"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) as you have with your .rows.count.  Might be good to also clarify where .cells() are from too

Comment: You forgot to include the `E` column and use the `Set` keyword: `Set NumElements = .Range(.Range("D6"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2)`. Also, you should rather declare it as a range, e.g. `Dim erg As Range: Set erg = .Range(.Range("D6"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2)` and then do `Dim arr As Variant: arr = erg.Value` avoiding the loop.

Answer (score 0):

### Fill Combobox with a Multi-Column Range

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Auto_Open()
    With Worksheets(5)
        Const cCount As Long = 2
        Dim erg As Range: Set erg = .Range("D6", .Range("D" & .Rows.Count) _
            .End(xlUp)).Resize(, cCount)
        Me.ComboBox1.ColumnCount = cCount
        Me.ComboBox1.List = erg.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate and explain the lines of code?